$G_x$ is $M$-generic iff for $\lambda(B)=1$ and $B\in M$ $x\in B$
Exercise
Let $\mathbb{B}=\text{Borel}([0,1])/\text{Null}$, $M$ be a countable ZFC-model and for $x\in [0,1]^V$ let $G_x=\{[B]:B\in M, B\text{ Borel},x\in B\}$. Show that $G_x$ is an $M$-generic ultrafilter if and only if $x\in B$ whenever $\lambda(B)=1$ and $B\in M$.
My solution
Suppose $x\notin B$. Then $x\in [0,1]\setminus B$. Therefore $[0,1]\setminus B \in G_x$. But since $\lambda(B)=1$, $\lambda([0,1]\setminus B)=0$. Now, in $M$, the set $D=\{[A]:A\text{ Borel},\lambda(A)=1\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{B}$. Since $G_x$ is $M$-generic, it must intersect $D$. This means there exists some $[A]\in G_x$ with $\lambda(A)=1$, but that's a contradiction.
For the reverse direction, assume $x\in B$ whenever $\lambda(B)=1$ and $B\in M$. First, let's show that $G_x$ is an ultrafilter:

If $[B_1],[B_2]\in G_x$, then $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, so $[B_1\cap B_2]\in G_x$.
If $[B_1]\in G_x$ and $[B_1]\subseteq [B_2]$, then $x\in B_2$, so $[B_2]\in G_x$.
For any $B$ Borel, either $x\in B$ or $x\in [0,1]\setminus B$, so either $[B]\in G_x$ or $[0,1]\setminus B\in G_x$.

Now for genericity: Let $D\in M$ be dense in $\mathbb{B}$, and consider the set $B_D=\bigcup \{B:[B]\in D\}$. Since $D$ is dense, $\lambda(B_D)=1$. Therefore $x\in B_D$ by our assumption. This means there exists some $B$ with $[B]\in D$ and $x\in B$, thus $[B]\in G_x\cap D$. Therefore $G_x$ meets every dense set in $M$, making it $M$-generic.
Is my proof correct?

The first line of the question uses the symbol $B$ for the Boolean algebra; the second line uses it for a Borel set. That's a recipe for confusion. But, however the confusion is resolved, I don't think that your $D$ is dense in $B$.  (By the way, I assume  you've seen and are  implicitly using some convention to make sense of statements like $x\in B$ that say that a set in $M$ has an element outside $M$.)

@AndreasBlass Sorry, the first $B$ should've been $\mathbb{B}$.

@AndreasBlass So, how can I correct it then? Btw, is the second half right?
